# Adding viewController as subview Swift Not showing any component

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I create a view controller vc in storyboard and place a View1 on it and add all constraint to it. Now I want to add a vc as a subview. I use this code :

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftMenuListIdentifier")      
self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
```

vc controller's add as subview to my current controller but it does not show any subview of vc controller'view means View1.

If I push vc controller to my current view controller then it shows View1.

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Please suggest what should I do . I want to add a view controller from storyboard as a subview.

Answer (score 2):

Kindly Follow below steps for resolve your issue.

1. First Create `UIViewController` object.
2. after that Add object as a `childviewcontroller`
    as Like (        self.addChildViewController("Your Controller Object"))
3. After that add controller on `self.view` as add `subview`.( `self.view.addSubview("Your Controller Object"))

i think it will working

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to push your vc, just add it to current viewcontroller using `addChildViewController(vc);`, [this link may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599858/how-to-properly-add-child-view-controller-in-ios-8-with-swift)

Comment: Hi!Thanks for reply I working now . but I need to add it on main window How do i do this? like this 
let currentWindow : UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!
        currentWindow.addSubview(vc.view)

Comment: what do you mean? do you want to make your child viewcontroller as rootviewcontroller? or do you to add your childviewcontroller to navigation hierarchy?